# How do I solve the volume bounded inside a solid

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Find the volume of the wedge in the first octant cut from the cylinder

$$ y^2+z^2=4 $$by the $yz$ plane and the plane $y=x$.  Indicated in the figure the slice used to compute the volume.

I cant find the answer, please guide me on how to solve these type of questions.

[The Solid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDJCW.png)

Comment: I think the standard approach would be to use a triple integral. First, choose the order of which you want to integrate over $x,y$ and $z$ ...

Comment: can I see a solution on how to do this? I have no clue on how to do this? :(

Comment: You could start by considering a slice of the geometry in the $xy$-plane, where $z$ is a fixed coordinate. The cross section is then a triangle. Could you formulate an area for the triangle, as a function of $z$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume can be calculated using a triple integral:

$$\int\int_{D}\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}dz\,\right)dxdy=\int\int_{D}\sqrt{4-y^2}\,dxdy$$

with the triangle $D=\{(x,y)\,|\,x<y\,,\,y<2\,,\,x>0\}$. Now

$$\int_0^2\int_0^y\sqrt{4-y^2}\,dxdy=\int_0^2y\sqrt{4-y^2}\,dy=\frac{8}{3}$$